# Crontab run script

Tags: scripts, scheduled

For example I want to schedule task using crontab:

```
*/2 * * * * /root/scripts/backup.sh
```

But nothing happens, `backup.sh` is not executed. Who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Check `/var/log/syslog`.

Change your cron line to:
    */2 * * * * /root/scripts/backup.sh >/tmp/backup.log 2>&1

so that you will get some log in the `/tmp/backup.log` file.

Comment: I want to ask an question: I need change mod of this script +x?

Comment: Yes, you need to.